# Cardano-graphql: Hasura migration failing for me

Tags: cardano-db-sync

I am having trouble setting up cardano-graphql service. It occurs when Hasura run the migration script to create a bunch a views on top of tables in cardan-db-sync. There error is:

`42703] FatalError: column block.merkle_root does not exist`

Sure enough I go login to postgres and see that merkle_root is not a column in the block table.

I am running testnet cardano node and testnet db-sync.

I have a multinode setup using nix-build:

Node1: `cardano-node, cardano-db-sync-extended (v 9.0)`

Node2: `cardano-node, cardano-graphql (v 4.0)`

Process that runs migration:

```
cardano-graphql/nix-build/hasura-cli/bin/hasura --skip-update-check --project /nix/store/is2s0kbvbxz04ih2ixzsg7kkyrmhizib-cardano-graphql-4.0.0/packages/api-cardano-db-hasura/hasura/project --endpoint http://localhost:8090 migrate apply --up all
```

My Hasura start stript:

```
export CARDANO_NODE_CONFIG_PATH="/home/ubuntu/cardano-my-node/testnet-config.json"
export HASURA_CLI_PATH=${PWD}/nix-build/hasura-cli/bin/hasura
export HASURA_URI=http://localhost:8090
export GENESIS_FILE_BYRON=${PWD}/config/network/testnet/genesis/byron.json
export GENESIS_FILE_SHELLEY=${PWD}/config/network/testnet/genesis/shelley.json
export POSTGRES_DB=testnet
export POSTGRES_HOST=*****
export POSTGRES_PASSWORD****
export POSTGRES_PORT=*****
export POSTGRES_USER=****
./nix-build/cardano-graphql/bin/cardano-graphql
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you make absolutely sure you are using the cardano-db-sync release 9.0? The specific field `merkle_root` [has been removed only some days ago](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/commit/f4988e3908b04d356d55bb4e37c2e66ef27f5924) and this change is still only in the master branch, unreleased.

Comment: Hi there thanks for the resonding. I just checked and here ran version on my terminal and got cardano-db-sync-extended 9.0.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git revision f8913ad07547b6dcbd47b9601a007ba8ece84052

Comment: Thanks Marek I was able to make things right after doing a git checkout tag/9.0.0 -b 9.0.0-branch